# Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module could not be found

Tags: windows, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I have a Xamarin Forms solution. I added sqlite-net-pcl as reference to all projects. It works fine on Android but crashes on Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. I have an IOS project but I don't have OSX at the moment to try it.

**I use this in the Windows projects to access the database:**

```
using System.IO;
using SQLite;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using HelloXamarin.Windows;
using Windows.Storage;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLiteDb))]

namespace HelloXamarin.Windows
{
   public class SQLiteDb : ISQLiteDb
    {
        public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection(string databaseName)
        {
            var documentsPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, databaseName);
            return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here are my references:**

[image: References]

**I get this exception when trying to access the database:**

The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.

Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

- at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.NativeMethods.sqlite3_win32_set_directory(UInt32 directoryType, String directoryPath)
- at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3..ctor()
- at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init() at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..cctor()

**I have no idea how to solve this, please help me!**

The whole solution is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/apspot/HelloXamarin

Answer (score 9):

For me, it worked by adding the [e_sqlite3 bundle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3) to the executable project

Comment: It works for me on Mac. Thanks.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: Get it from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3

Answer (score 3):

By this time the issue is still [open](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19396). So before they come with some solid fix, you can use [this work around](https://gist.github.com/FuncLun/fff2c63c7d37f4ff3d20f70e00bb241f), to solve the issue for now.

> Add one helper class

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace SQLitePCL
{
    public class NativeLibraryHack
    {
        public static bool Hacked { get; private set; }

        public static bool DoHack()
        {
            if (Hacked) return true;

            try
            {
                const string runtimeFolderName = "/runtimes";

                var destinationPath = typeof(SQLitePCL.raw).Assembly.Location
                    .Replace("\\", "/");
                var destinationLength = destinationPath.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                var destinationDirectory = destinationPath.Substring(0, destinationLength) + runtimeFolderName;

                var sourcePath = new Uri(typeof(SQLitePCL.raw).Assembly.CodeBase)
                    .AbsolutePath;
                var sourceLength = sourcePath.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                var sourceDirectory = sourcePath.Substring(0, sourceLength) + runtimeFolderName;

                if (Directory.Exists(sourceDirectory))
                    CopyFilesRecursively(new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory), new DirectoryInfo(destinationDirectory));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Ignore Exception
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }

            return (Hacked = true);
        }

        private static void CopyFilesRecursively(
            DirectoryInfo source,
            DirectoryInfo target
        )
        {
            foreach (var dir in source.GetDirectories())
                CopyFilesRecursively(dir, target.CreateSubdirectory(dir.Name));

            foreach (var file in source.GetFiles())
            {
                try
                {
                    var destinationFile = Path.Combine(target.FullName, file.Name);
                    if (!File.Exists(destinationFile))
                        file.CopyTo(destinationFile);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Ignore Exception
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> And add the hack before your db migration script, I am using web api 2
>   so i did on `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`

```
    NativeLibraryHack.DoHack();

    using (KSDBContext db = new KSDBContext())
    {
        db.Database.Migrate();                 
    }
```

Comment: its not working for me. Which connection string for sql lite do you have?

Comment: This worked for me after a lot of other things did not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the SQLite Extensions.

1. Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates
2. Go to Online, then search for SQLite.
3. Download SQLite for Windows Runtime

[image]

4. In your Windows Project, Add Reference and ensure you add the extension.

[image]

Also remove Microsoft.VCLibs from your references.

Comment: I added SQLite for Windows Runtime but the problem still exists: [link](https://ibb.co/iUwYo5)

Comment: Do you have the Visual Studio Runtime C++ 2013 library referenced as well?

Comment: If you mean "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package..." than it has been added as reference, you can see it on [this screenshot](https://ibb.co/iUwYo5)

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps. That sorted it out for me.

1. Go to References
2. Add Reference
3. Extensions.
4. Check"Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps"
5. OK

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm unable to check it at the moment because I have Visual Studio licensing problems :(